# Automaticaly creating users in Oracle Apex based on table values

Tags: oracle, authentication, plsql, oracle-apex

Is there a way to automatically create a user in my application based on values in a table?

So I have a table named `EMP` as employee in that table I have attributes `name, surname, username` and `password`. What do I need to do to automatically create a user account in my application when a new employee is inserted into the database?

I have no idea where to start, is that done in processes or is there a pre-built feature that covers this?
Is there a sample code that everyone just uses and adapts to their needs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In such a case, maybe it would be better to use **custom authentication** scheme instead of default, built-in Apex authentication.

---

How to create new users? Just *insert* them into the table. It would be a good idea to create a **package** which contains procedures used to manipulate with users' data.

You shouldn't store passwords as text for security reasons.

For example:

```
procedure p_create_user (p_name     in varchar2, p_surname  in varchar2, 
                         p_username in varchar2, p_password in varchar2) 
is
  l_hash raw (2000);
begin
  l_hash :=
    dbms_crypto.hash (
      utl_i18n.string_to_raw (p_password, 'AL32UTF8'),
      dbms_crypto.hash_sh1);

  insert into emp (name, surname, username, password)
    values
    (p_name, p_surname, p_username, l_hash);
end;
```

---

In Apex, authentication scheme requires you to create your own function (and set its name into the "Authentication Function Name" property) which accepts username/password combination and returns Boolean: TRUE (if credentials are valid) or FALSE (if not). Note that parameters' names MUST be `p_username` and `p_password`.

Use code similar to that in previous procedure:

```
function f_auth (p_username in varchar2, p_password in varchar2)
return boolean
is
  l_pwd emp.password%type;
begin
  select password
    into l_pwd
    from emp
    where username = p_username;

  return l_pwd = dbms_crypto.hash (
                   utl_i18n.string_to_raw (p_password, 'AL32UTF8'),
                   dbms_crypto.hash_sh1);

end;
```

---

That's all you need for *basic*  functionality. You can add another procedure to let users change their password etc.

Comment: I'm sorry but just to reiterate.1)  1st code is used to "encrypt" data so i dont actually save text data of the password and username right ? If so what are the p_name and p_surname for ? (i get that those are attributes in my table but does that mean they will get encrypted too ? if i have more attributes in the emp table do i need to mention them in the procedure as well ? Also do i create the procedure during the process of creating a custom authentication ? or are those created somwhere else ?

Comment: Only password will be crypted. Other parameters are here so that you'd "create user" with that procedure only. Include other attributes into the procedure's parameter list. Procedure (and function) should be part of the package, created separately in e.g. SQL Developer (or whichever tool you use) (not during process of authentication schema creation in Apex).

Comment: 2) If i create my own authentication scheme as you instructed where do i set authentication roles and do i still keep my login details as administrator or do i need to set it again ?  I'm extremely sorry for the surplus of questions after you explained everything so nicely but I'm afraid my oracle apex knowledge is extremely limited so i need to ask more question to be able to execute everything. Thank you in advance !

Comment: Roles will also be set separately (either in the EMP table, so you'd - for example - set CB_ADMIN column's value to "1" for yourself, CB_READ_ONLY for someone else, etc.). To create authorization roles (which is what is being used to tell who is allowed to do what), you'd use Shared Components' "Authorization schemes"; create set of functions which will accept username (i.e. :APP_USER) as a parameter and return Boolean, saying whether that *someone* is admin, read-only user, or whatever else. Then use authorization schema on every page (you'll find that property on the right hand side).

Comment: **Alternatively** (to *everything* I said so far), you could abandon this idea and use Apex APIs, e.g. CREATE USER procedure (https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/20.2/aeapi/CREATE_USER-Procedure.html#GUID-95721E36-4DAB-4BCA-A6F3-AC2BACC52A66). I, on the other hand, prefer keeping users in my own tables, that's why I suggested such an approach.

Comment: I see, thank you so much for the explanation but I'm extremely low on time so i will be using the alternative this time but i will definitely save this thread for any further projects so your efforts wont be in vain. Again a million times thank you for all the help you provided during the process of creating my application ! <3

Comment: No problem; good luck!